# PostGIS 2.0 function returns pseudo-type record rather than table

Tags: postgis

I'm writing a PL/pgSQL function to take a geography column and output a fishnet that bounds the extent of the shapes.

I've tried to emulate the examples in docs and tutorials, but the function returns a pseudo-type result, not a usable table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Fishnet(
        nrow integer, 
        ncol integer,
        geo_table varchar,
        geom_column varchar)
RETURNS Table( ids text, geom geometry)
AS $$
DECLARE
    collected_geom geometry;
    xmin numeric;
    xmax numeric;
    ymin numeric;
    ymax numeric;
    xsize numeric;
    ysize numeric;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT st_collect("'||$4||'") FROM "'||$3||'"' INTO collected_geom;
    xmax := st_xmin(collected_geom);
    xmin := st_xmax(collected_geom);
    ymin := st_ymin(collected_geom);
    ymax := st_ymax(collected_geom);
    xsize := abs(xmax - xmin) / $2;
    ysize := abs(ymax - ymin) / $1;
    return query 
        SELECT
            i+1||'-'||j+1 as ids,
            ST_Translate(cell, j * xsize + xmax, i * ysize + ymin) AS geom
        FROM 
                generate_series(0, $1 - 1) AS i,
                generate_series(0, $2 - 1) AS j,
                (SELECT ('POLYGON((0 0, 0 '||ysize||', '||xsize||' '||ysize||', '||xsize||' 0,0 0))')::geometry AS cell) AS temp;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But while my output should have two distinct columns, ids and the geom, I'm getting pseudo-type record that looks like:
(id, geom)

what am I missing?

Comment: Don't cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126148/pl-pgsql-return-query-gives-psuedo-type-record-rather-than-table

Comment: Lesson learned. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This PostgreSQL function is called a [set-returning function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), which has 1 or more columns of different data types. To get to the data in the columns, use one of either:

- `SELECT * FROM ST_Fishnet(<...>)` to return all columns of the set; or
- `SELECT (ST_Fishnet(<...>)).geom` to return only one column (e.g., `geom`) of the set

(Note `<...>` are the parameters to the set-returning function).